# dynamically lazy loading of objects does not work

Tags: hibernate

I am using spring + hibernate in my project; I have two classes `Reminder` and `Client`
in class reminder i have added a relationship of many to one for client and it is by default eagerly loaded. I want this Object graph most of the scenarios in my project so i have set fetch type eager for client in reminder class

```
Class Reminder {
    @ManyToOne
    Client client;
}
```

but for one or two scenarios i want to keep initialization of this object client lazy;

so i have added in method for fetching reminders is like below

```
Criteria c = session.createCriteria();
c.setFetchMode("client", FetchMode.SELECT); 
hibernateTemplate.findByCriteria(criteria);
```

it is not working; it still loads client objects with reminder

while reverse (from lazy to eager) is working fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the api doc:

> public static final FetchMode SELECT
>
> ```
> Fetch eagerly, using a separate select. Equivalent to fetch="select"
> ```

AFAIK, if a mapping is marked as lazy, you may fetch eagerly using a criteria or HQL query, but you can't do the reverse : if a mapping is marked as eager, then it'll always be fetched eagerly.

Comment: thanks for replying; but i found on net that api doc for FetchMode.Select is wrong; it fetches lazily

Comment: The doc is correct, fetching means how we load data where are lazy true/false is whether or not we load the data.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't have lazy loading on single ended association that can be null(many-to-one, one-to-one). Hibernate3 supports lazy loading of individual **fields** using some **byte code stuff**.

**From JBoss wiki:**

Use `lazy="true"` on , and  mappings to enable lazy loading of individual scalar value-typed properties (a somewhat exotic case). Requires bytecode instrumentation of compiled persistent classes for the injection of interception code. Can be overriden in HQL with FETCH ALL PROPERTIES.

Use `lazy="no-proxy"` on single-valued associations to enable lazy fetching without the use of a proxy. Requires bytecode instrumentation for the injection of interception code.

Thanks.

Comment: Thank you, but it is not for oneToMany associations also;i tried it; it's not working and can u please give me sample code for byte code stuff for lazy initialization

Comment: Check out this link from [JBoss](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/performance.html#performance-fetching-lazyproperties).