# Efficient Hibernate criteria for join returning many partial duplicates

Tags: java, hibernate, optimization, criteria, hibernate-criteria

I'm fetching a long list of entities which refer to others which refer to... and, at the end, usually of all them refer to a single `user` as their `owner`. Not really surprising as what's queried are entities belonging to a single `user`. There are more parts duplicated in many rows; actually, just a small percentage are unique data. As the query seems to be slow, I though I could gain a bit by fetching things separately using

```
criteria.setFetchMode(path, FetchMode.SELECT);
```

This works in my above case, but when querying over many users (as admin), it gets terrible, as hibernate issues a separate query for *every* `user`, instead of something like

```
SELECT * FROM User WHERE id IN (?, ?, ..., ?)
```

or *not fetching them* at all (which can't get any worse than one query per entity). I wonder what am I missing?

*So instead of fetching a lot of redundant data, I ran into the 1+N problem, where obviously 1+1 queries would do.*

- Is there a way to instruct Hibernate to use the right query?
- Is there a way to prevent Hibernate from fetching the owners by specifying it in the criteria itself (rather than putting `fetch=FetchType.LAZY` on the field; the laziness should be query-specific)?

---

I don't think it matters, but my classes are like

```
class Child {
    @ManyToOne Father father;
    @ManyToOne Mother mother;
    ...
}
class Father {
    @ManyToOne User owner;
    ...
}
class Mother {
    @ManyToOne User owner;
    ...
}
```

and the query is like

```
createCriteria(Child.class)
.add(Restrictions.in("id", idList))
.add(Restrictions.eq("isDeleted", false))

.createAlias("Father", "f")
.add(Restrictions.eq("f.isDeleted", false))
.setFetchMode("f.owner", FetchMode.SELECT)

.createAlias("Mother", "m")
.add(Restrictions.eq("m.isDeleted", false))
.setFetchMode("m.owner", FetchMode.SELECT)

.list();
```

The important part is that `owner` does not get used and can be proxied. The javadoc for `FetchMode.SELECT` says

> Fetch eagerly, using a separate select

so it basically promises 1+1 querying which I want rather than "using a separate select per entity".

Comment: N+1 issue? Have you tried FetchMode.JOIN or FetchMode.SUBSELECT ?

Comment: @dimitrisli Sure, N+1 instead if 2. `FetchMode.JOIN` is what I wanted to avoid as it reads a lot of duplicated data. `SUBSELECT` exists in `org.hibernate.annotations.FetchMode`, but not in `org.hibernate.FetchMode`, which I'm using (I prefer the pre-JPA criteria).

Comment: Can you share your query criteria?

Comment: You've got the right idea with the FetchMode.SELECT, but I'm confused by the part about querying many users. Are you issuing a query per user or is Hibernate doing it?

Comment: @JohnScattergood Hibernate is doing it, no idea why. What I wanted to see is the bulk fetch `SELECT * FROM User WHERE id IN (?, ?, ..., ?)` and if you could provide an example where it really happens, I'll try to steer my code towards it.

Comment: @JohnScattergood Yes. It's a list of ids of all "children" the current user is allowed to see. It gets fetched by a separate HQL query (this is a workaround for [HHH-10442](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34104961/581205)). Quite often, `child.father.owner` is the current user and so is `child.mother.owner`, so there's nothing to fetch. But an admin can see everything and then the owners are various users which get fetched one by one.

Comment: Ok, for completeness which version of hibernate?

Comment: @JohnScattergood 5.1.0.Final. Using legacy [org.hibernate.Criteria](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.1/userguide/html_single/appendices/Legacy_Criteria.html) rather than the [new shiny thingy](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.1/userguide/html_single/chapters/query-criteria/Criteria.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> unless the property is declared with
>   `@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)`, you can't change anything

True, at least for the time being, until fetch profile capabilities are extended to provide the ability to change eager loading to lazy.

> the default is `FetchType.EAGER`, which is stupid, as it can't be
>   overridden

True, and I agree that it is bad, but in Hibernate native API everything is lazy by default; it is JPA that mandates to-one associations to be eager unless explicitly specified otherwise.

> using criteria.setFetchMode(path, FetchMode.SELECT) is pointless as
>   it's always a no-op (either it gets ignored because of the
>   non-overridable eagerness of the property or the property is lazy
>   already)!

With it you should be able to override other lazy fetch modes. See [HHH-980](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-980) and [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6368605/dynamically-lazy-loading-of-objects-does-not-work#comment7461108_6368779) from one of the lead Hibernate contributors about the javadoc confusion.

> fetching lazily leads by default to the 1+N problem

It has nothing to do with lazy loading specifically, it is the default for eager loading as well if you don't fetch the eagerly loaded association in the same query.

> it can be controlled via a class-level `@BatchSize` annotation

You have to place it on class-level for it to take effect on to-one associations with that entity; [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20703366/4754790) is helpful. For collection associations (to-many associations with that entity defined in other entities) you have the flexibility to define it separately for each association.

Answer (score 3):

[Fetch profiles](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch20.html#performance-fetching-profiles) are meant to help you achieve what you want, but are very limited at the time being and you can override the default fetch plan/strategy only with the join-style fetch profiles (you can make a lazy association eager, but not vice versa). However, you could use this [trick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31964104/4754790) to invert that behaviour: Make the association lazy by default and enable the profile by default for all sessions/transactions. Then **disable** the profile in transactions in which you want lazy loading.

IMHO the solution above looks too cumbersome, and the approach I use in most use cases to avoid both loading of redundant data and N+1 selects problem is to make associations lazy and define [batch size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35032559/batchsize-a-smart-or-stupid-use/35039402#35039402).

Comment: Very helpful! I guess, I was wrongly assuming that "Fetch eagerly, using a separate select" means what it says, but it seems to mean "don't fetch (and when needed later, fetch one-by-one, unless batch size is specified on the class (rather than on the scalar property where it gets silently ignored)). And unless property is declared with `fetch=FetchType.LAZY`, the `FetchMode` gets just ignored.

Comment: @maaartinus Your association is eager, that means it will always be fetched one-by-one if you don't fetch it with a fetch join as part of the query (which causes lots of redundant data for collections). Take a look at [this blog](https://vladmihalcea.com/2014/12/15/eager-fetching-is-a-code-smell/) for more details about the subject.

Comment: <rant>The sad thing is that " we may override the global fetch plan, but only for LAZY associations". I'd call it a bug, but bugs can get filed against specification and the Javadoc is rather silent about such details (but silently ignoring something is nearly always unexpected and therefore wrong). And the default is a code smell.</rant> Anyway, thank you!

Comment: Could you kindly look at [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36828605/581205) trying to summarize the gotchas I ran into?

Comment: @maaartinus Sure, I added [another answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36841089/4754790) because it was to large to fit in the comment(s).

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a small project to demonstrate the behavior.  The SQL generated from your criteria is as follows:

```
select
    this_.id as id1_0_4_,
    this_.father_id as father_i3_0_4_,
    this_.isDeleted as isDelete2_0_4_,
    this_.mother_id as mother_i4_0_4_,
    f1_.id as id1_1_0_,
    f1_.isDeleted as isDelete2_1_0_,
    f1_.owner_id as owner_id3_1_0_,
    user5_.id as id1_3_1_,
    user5_.isDeleted as isDelete2_3_1_,
    m2_.id as id1_2_2_,
    m2_.isDeleted as isDelete2_2_2_,
    m2_.owner_id as owner_id3_2_2_,
    user7_.id as id1_3_3_,
    user7_.isDeleted as isDelete2_3_3_ 
from
    Child this_ 
inner join
    Father f1_ 
        on this_.father_id=f1_.id 
left outer join
    User user5_ 
        on f1_.owner_id=user5_.id 
inner join
    Mother m2_ 
        on this_.mother_id=m2_.id 
left outer join
    User user7_ 
        on m2_.owner_id=user7_.id 
where
    this_.id in (
        ?, ?
    ) 
    and this_.isDeleted=? 
    and f1_.isDeleted=? 
    and m2_.isDeleted=?
```

1. Changing the FetchMode in the criteria API did not affect the query.  The owner data is still queried.
2. The Ids are in the "in" clause and Hibernate did not issue separate queries for each Id.

As mentioned in other answers, if the entity relation is set to `EAGER`, ie JPA default, then you can't change the fetch mode in the Criteria API. The fetch mode needs to be changed to `LAZY`.

You can see it [here](https://github.com/jscattergood/hibernateCriteriaDemo/blob/master/src/test/java/com/example/model/CriteriaTests.java)

Comment: Good job! I'm playing with your project and will post what I find out. I guess, the one-by-one loading occurs later when the owners get accessed (I was rather sure they don't get accessed, but I was wrong).

Comment: @JohnScattergood Add `session.clear()` after flushing to reproduce OP's behaviour. In your test, all of the affected entities are still in the persistence context with their lazy associations initialized.

Comment: ... and make the associations from `Father` and `Mother` to `User` lazy. Then when accessing `owner`s on `Father`s and `Mother`s you'll get N+1 selects problem. Sorry, forgot to mention that.

Comment: @DraganBozanovic Thanks.  I was trying to configure it exactly as the OP wrote. He said his relations were EAGER and that he was changing it in the Criteria. I agree that it doesn't work. That being said I wouldn't call session.clear() in this case because I'm not dealing with a large dataset in one transaction.

Comment: But @DraganBozanovic is right. The reason for `session.clear()` is to simulate what happens when I'm fetching data. I start with an empty session, as they were stored long long ago in a different transaction. The simplest way to simulate this is to clear the session after the data were stored. Anyway, using your project and his answer, I learned a lot.

Answer (score 1):

To summarize my frustration... Hibernate is full of surprises (bugs?) in this respect:

- unless the property is declared with `@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)`, you can't change anything
- the default is `FetchType.EAGER`, which is stupid, as it can't be overridden
- **using `criteria.setFetchMode(path, FetchMode.SELECT)` is pointless** as it's always a no-op (either it gets ignored because of the non-overridable eagerness of the property or the property is lazy already)!
- fetching lazily leads by default to the 1+N problem
- it can be controlled via a class-level `@BatchSize` annotation
- **placing a `@BatchSize` annotation on a scalar field gets silently ignored**

In order to get what I wanted (two SQL queries), I need just two things:

- declare the property with `@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)`
- place `@BatchSize(size=aLot)` on the class of the property

That's simple, but a bit hard to find out (because of all the ignored things above). I haven't looked into fetch profiles yet.